What does "Tris dies" mean in "Ritchie's Fabulae Faciles"?
From Ritchie's Fabulae Faciles:

Tris dies per totam insulam matrem quaerebat; tandem quarto die ad templum Dianae pervenit.
http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/ritchie.html

What does "Tris dies" mean? Is it a typo? Should it be "tres dies" (three days)?

The third declension masculine and feminine accusative plural ending has two alternatives: -ēs and -īs.
See, for example, this question and its answers and comments for a discussion on the matter.
Therefore the tris you found is likely to be just a variant of tres, probably a conscious choice by the author.
Replace it with tres would not change the meaning, but it may impact reception; the ending -es is much more widely known.

Why did the author use a much-less-known case ending, if his intention was to write a story that's easy to read by beginners in Latin? Makes no sense.

@FlatAssembler That is odd indeed. Perhaps at that point the reader is expected to be familiar with the standard form and the author wanted to mention a variant? Exposure to the variation found out there is good, but not knowing the material I can't judge if this one comes too early.
